# Java. Simple TimerTask for each value of array

Tags: java, arrays, timertask

I have problem with printing out the each value of certain array with certain duration of time.
For example I have array with values: "Value1", "Value2", "Value3". I want to output "Value1", after 5 sec "Value2", after 5 second "Value3".
Instead, All Values of arrays are printout 3 times.
If you could help to me, I will be so gratefull ))
Thank you.

### Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Timer2 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start = new Date().getTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {

                public void run() {
                    String[] arrayElements = { "value1", "value2", "value3",
                            "value4" };
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayElements.length; i++)
                        System.out.println(arrayElements[i]);

                }
            }, new Date(start));
            start += 1000;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: cross-posted and answered over 2 hours ago: http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/41732-timertask-each-value-array.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution from my answer in cross-post that uses scheduleAtFixedRate:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

class Timer2 {

   private static final String[] ARRAY_ELEMENTS = {"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"};

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final Timer utilTimer = new Timer();
      utilTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
         private int index = 0;

         public void run() {
            System.out.println(ARRAY_ELEMENTS[index]);
            index++;
            if (index >= ARRAY_ELEMENTS.length) {
               utilTimer.cancel();
            }
         }
      }, 5000L, 5000L);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do what you have described you want to do is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    String[] arrayElements = { "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4" };

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayElements.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arrayElements[i]);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }   
}
```

If you must use a TimerTask then you could do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    String[] arrayElements = { "value1", "value2", "value3",
    "value4" };

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayElements.length; i++) {
        final String value = arrayElements[i];
         new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(value);
                }
         }, new Date(start));

         start += 5000;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the print loop in the TimeTask.run() so when it is executed, all the value is printed out at once. What you need to do is to create a time task for each array elements. Something like:

`String[] arrayElements = {"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"};
for (final String arrayElement : arrayElements)
{
  new java.util.Timer().schedule(
    new java.util.TimerTask()
    { 
      public void run()
      {
        System.out.println(arrayElement);
      }
    },
    new Date(start)
  );
  start+=1000;
}`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why create a new TimerTask for each element rather than simply loop through the array elements in one TimerTask. Please see my solution in cross-post: [Java-Forums cross-post](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/41732-timertask-each-value-array.html#post194138)

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I was trying to answer the direct question - create TimerTask for each array value. What to do what each value can be much more than just printing it out.

Comment: The original question I see is how to print out the element of an array each xxx msec. I see nothing in the original question specifying that each element must have its own TimerTask object, and again, the OP is better off not doing this.  Better off using Timer's scheduleAtFixedRate.  Please see below.

Comment: It won't let me delete down-vote.  I'll up-vote something else of yours to compensate.  Sorry.